# What is the purpose of filesystem.size on a LiveCD?

Tags: live-usb, live-cd

There is */casper/filesystem.squashfs* on the most LiveCDs of Ubuntu and derivatives that apparently contains the size value of the filesystem tree before compression. Some LiveCD customization articles mention that this file needs to be present in order for the system to boot correctly, but I managed to run a casper-based LiveCD system without it. And grepping through the contents of the `casper` package I cannot find it either.

What is it for? Will I benefit from including it into my live distribution?

Comment: Related: [How does Ubiquity determine the required disk space before installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1137929/37165), which has some details on how the installer use the filesystem.size file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filesystem.size is needed when a LiveCD is used to perform installation.

Ubuntu Community Wiki Help has documented briefly in this page: [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization). Refer to the content under **8. Producing the CD image - Assembling the file system**.

> Update the filesystem.size file, which is needed by the installer:
>
> ```
> sudo su
> printf $(du -sx --block-size=1 edit | cut -f1) > extract-cd/casper/filesystem.size
> exit
> ```

Jump to the content by using **Find in This Page...** in the web browser: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type `filesystem.size` as the keyword. That is all.